# Gulp Watch JS loop infinito

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulpjs, gulpfile

Sou novo estudante de Gulp, e eu fiz esse `watch` para se os meus arquivos javascripts sofrerem alteração, ele executar o `build-js`. Mas quando eu executo o Gulp, ele compila tudo certo mas ele fica executando o `build-js` num loop infinito. O que fiz de errado?

Obrigado!

```
gulp.task('build-js', function (cb) {
            pump([
                gulp.src('lib/*.js'),
                uglify(),
                gulp.dest('dist')
            ],
                cb
            );
        });

gulp.task('watch-js', function () {
    gulp.watch('lib/*.js', ['build-js']);
})

gulp.task('default', ['build-js', 'watch-js']);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema pode ser por estar aplicando o `watch` em todos os `js`, onde dispara se qualquer um deles alterar. Tente aplicar dessa forma:

```
gulp.watch(['lib/*.js', '!lib/bundle.js'], ['build-js']);
```

Comment: é isso mesmo @Lucas, o problema está que o `bundle.js` é atualizado na primeira vez, que desencadea o `watch` no loop infinito porque é ele que é sempre alterado. Mas este código de `!lib/bundle.js` não funcionou :(

Comment: o caminho `lib/bundle.js` esta correto @Jackson?

Comment: Sim. Só para confirmar... o que você diz aí é: 
Pegue todos os arquivos `.js` na pasta `lib`, mas ignore o arquivo `bundle.js` na pasta `lib` ? Isso parece estar muito certo, mas não está ignorando.. :(

Comment: Isso mesmo! Podemos continuar no chat Jackson se você quiser

Comment: Faz sentido isso... mas infelizmente não funciona aqui =(